# A. n'aimait pas que je regarde ce film

Tags: subjonctif

> A. n'aimait pas que je **regarde** ce film.

Donc, il faudrait employer le subjonctif *regarde* dans cette phrase malgré le fait que j'ai regardé ce film dans le passé ?

Les actions sont simultanées : A. est entré, a vu que je regardais un film et ne l'a pas aimé.

Answer (score 2):

Autrefois, il fallait utiliser [l'imparfait du subjonctif](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/imperfect-subjunctive/) :

> A. n'aimait pas que je regardasse ce film.

De nos jours, l'imparfait du subjonctif est réservé pour la littérature ; le subjonctif présent le remplace :

> A. n'aimait pas que je regarde ce film.

Comment: l'imparfait n'irait pas ici?

Comment: Non. *Aimer* exige le subjonctif.

Comment: Alors, on ne peut pas dire: A. n'aimait pas que je montais à cheval pendant les vacances d'été? Qu'est-qui ce passe lorsque l'action est dans le passe?

Comment: Dans cet exemple, on peut utiliser le passé du subjonctif : *A. n'aimait pas que j'aie monté ...*

Comment: *Il n'aimait pas que je montais à cheval [...]* est une faute grossière mais *Il n'aimais pas **quand** je montais à cheval [...]* est possible.

Comment: La phrase de Lambie peut être écrite de deux façons : _A. n'aimait pas que j'aie monté..._ et _A. n'aimait pas que je monte_, non ? La 2ème signifie que A. a vu que j'étais sur le cheval et il n'a pas aimé alors que la 1ère décrit une simultanéité. C'est correct ?

Comment: Tout à fait, on peut utiliser le subjonctif soit au présent, soit au passé.